# query R from neo4j

Tags: r, neo4j

Tried to connect to `neo4j` from `R`

Ran this:

```
install.packages('RCurl')
install.packages('RJSONIO')
library('bitops')
library('RCurl')
library('RJSONIO')
query <- function(querystring) {
  h = basicTextGatherer()
  curlPerform(url="http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query",
          postfields=paste('query',curlEscape(querystring), sep='='),
          writefunction = h$update,
          verbose = FALSE
  )

  result <- fromJSON(h$value())

  data <- data.frame(t(sapply(result$data, unlist)))
  names(data) <- result.json$columns
  data
}
```

Then I am running:

```
q<-"MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p.name"
data<-query(q)
```

But it is giving the error:

```
Error in query(q) : object 'result.json' not found
```

I have updated R studio to `0.98.501` and R is at `R-3.1.0-snowleopard.pkg`.  Why am I getting this error?  Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you're using `Content-type` and `accept` header set to `application/json`. If this does not help, try to pull in a proxy like charlesproxy between neo4j and the R client to see what's going over the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this to work from a fork by Mark Needham

```
library('RCurl')
library('RJSONIO')

query <- function(querystring) {
 h = basicTextGatherer()
 curlPerform(url="http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
             postfields=paste('query',curlEscape(querystring), sep='='),
             writefunction = h$update,
             verbose = FALSE
 )

 result <- fromJSON(h$value())

 data <- data.frame(t(sapply(result$data, unlist)))
 names(data) <- result$columns

 data
```

}

Then just ran:

```
data <- query("START n = node(*) RETURN COUNT(n) AS count")
```

Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a clear error:

```
MATCH (p:Person) RETURN a.name
```

You're matching a node called "p", and returning the name property on a node called "a".

Try this instead:

```
MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p.name
```

Comment: sorry was typo on my part.  Error still happens.